# web.config File Issue

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-config

I have recently added a domain to my website on Azure. When I used the given domain by Azure I had no issues with loading it on my web browser but when I changed to my custom domain this issue has been blocking me from gaining access to my website.

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

**Runtime Error**

**Description:** An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

**Details:** To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Let me know if there are any suggestions or changes needed in my config file

My web.config file

```
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
 <customErrors mode="Off"/>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
 <compilers>
   <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
     type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
   <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
     type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
     warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
 </compilers>
</system.codedom>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Server Error in '/' Application.**
When ever we change the custom domain , changes has to be done in TSL/SSL Settings.
Need to add New TSL/SSL bindings by selecting custom Domain (New Domain) name, Private certificate and TSL/SSL Type.
The custom domain remains insecure even after being added. Add the SSL certificate if necessary.

Follow the below procedure for adding SSL Certificate:

1. In the `TLS / SSL settings` > Select '+ Add TLS / SSL Binding'
2. Choose the custom domain and public certificate or `.pfx` needs to be imported for it > `Add`.
3. In the section of Custom Domains > "Add binding" option.
4. As SNI, select your domain's certificate and TLS/SSL type.